# QuickBooks Desktop Invoice Integration and InvoiceGroupLine Limitations

Tags: desktop, quickbooks, invoice

I have been Integrating Invoice module of Quickbooks Desktop Enterprise with an application using "qbxml", i encountered that with `InvoiceLine` i can send many fields including custom fields, But when it comes to `InvoiceGroupLine` i can't send the following which i need too:

1.Service Date field;

2.Other1;

3.Other2.

(all of the above mentioned fields to be added at the last row of GroupItem where description of it is placed as shown in picture below.)

[image]

Also attached picture shows the custom field called "Employee" was populated at the first line of this, which should be at the bottom where the last description is.

Secondly, you can see i was unable to pass through 'service date' and 'other1' which is 'Patient' and 'other2' which is 'MR Number' fields for GroupItem.

The reason why i asked about population on the bottom is because, only the last line of GroupItem copies to Print/Print Preview of Invoices in Quickbooks.

How can i able to achieve my goal of sending over these fields as i mentioned above to QuickBooks to their respective places/positions and fields? thanks.